# Toggle widget stops working after installing any new app

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm designing a toggle widget that mutes and unmutes the media volume. It works great until I install any new app... Then it just stops working. There is no force close or anything, it just doesn't do anything when i press it. (It will start working again if I delete the widget and add it again.) With log cat I don't see any messages related to my app.

I have posted code below, but if you could tell me like conceptually what happens to the home screen when I install a new app, and where basically I could troubleshoot that would help too.

Thanks for your help. I've been at this for days and just can't figure it out. I'm on stock android 4.04 Galaxy Nexus.

```
public class JCrashWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "com.JCrash.widget.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "com.JCrash.widget.ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE";
private RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews("com.JCrash", R.layout.widgetstyle1 );

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);    

    Intent mediaClick = new Intent(context, JCrashWidget.class);
    mediaClick.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0, mediaClick, 0);       
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.headphonesid, pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds,remoteViews );
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, JCrashWidget.class);

    int cVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
            if (cVol == 0)
            {
                cVol = myPrefs.getInt("PREVIOUS_VOLUME", 0);
                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.headphonesid,R.drawable.headphones);
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, cVol,
                    AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                    cVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            }

            else 
            {
                prefsEditor.putInt("PREVIOUS_VOLUME", cVol);
                prefsEditor.commit();
                cVol = myPrefs.getInt("PREVIOUS_VOLUME", 0);

                remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.headphonesid,R.drawable.headphones_off);
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

                cVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            }
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, remoteViews);             
        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! I had to set the OnClickPendingIntent again in the OnReceive method as well as the OnUpdate method. I'll just make a function set the pending intent for the widget and call it from both OnReceive and OnUpdate.

Comment: can you  please show your code after you fixed if?  i have the same problam and cant fixed it after doing what you sais. Thanks!